# Why does the user's IP is a local one when accessing the page using the global URL?

Tags: asp.net, url, networking, web, ip

I am logging every user's IP when they access the company's page.

There are two ways to access the page from inside the local network:

```
http://company/webpage
```

and

```
https://webpage.company.com
```

What bugs me is that even when the users use the `https` global IP, their accesses are still recorded on database with their IP as `10.50.1.12` or `10.50.1.100`.

Does that means that the browser or something else is redirecting the `https://webpage.company.com` to `company/webpage`? Or does that mean that I'm using a flawed method to log the users IP?

Another way to ask my question (just to make sure I'm being clear): if I'm accessing my Internet web page from inside the LAN network, am I effectively going outside my network and then back? If not, where am I going wrong with my logging?

Code used to log user's IP:

```
user.LastIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

I'm curious about this because I want to make sure the users inside the company will access the page using **exclusively the LAN Network**. The goal is to **save bandwidth usage**, which is scarce.

Edit:

Pinging the `https://webpage.company.com` from inside the LAN network will result in a reply from a global IP address like `194.xxx.xxx.xxx`. So I'm clearly getting the user's IP wrongly. What would be the ideal way of retrieving the IP from the page accessing entity?

Comment: `"am I effectively going outside my network and then back?"` - That would be some pretty inefficient routing, and I suspect the network equipment is smarter than that.  Why clog up the lower-bandwidth connection when a higher-bandwidth route is available?

Comment: I suppose the network equipment would have to look up the DNS from a provider to check that `https://webpage.company.com` is actually local. That itself is effectively an Internet connection.

Comment: `"That itself is effectively an Internet connection"` - No it isn't.  It's a hostname.  And once the address of that host is resolved, connections go to that address.  If that address is known by the routing tables to be on a given LAN connection, that's where the traffic for that host is routed.

Comment: Inside your network do those domains resolve to local addresses?

Comment: No. If I ping the https://webpage.company.com, reply will come from a 186.xxx.xxx.xxx IP.

Answer (score 1):

Access to http://company/webpage will result in a DNS lookup of the host name "company". To resolve this, DNS will need a fully qualified domain name (fqdn), so it will add a top level domain (according to the configured search list in the client). In this example, it seems fair to assume that the fqdn will be "company.com". This, in turn, may very well resolve to the same IP address as the "webpage.company.com". You can check this by using dns lookup utilities like 'nslookup' and 'dig', or simply by using 'ping company' and 'ping webpage.company.com'.

The users IP addresses you mention, 10.50.1.12 and 10.50.1.100, seems to be the local IP addresses of the client hosts. I base this assumption on the fact that these IP addresses come from the RFC-1918 address range which is used for internal addresses. My guess is that these are the correct IP addresses, and that your logging works fine.

The users IP address you will log from accessing 'http://company/webpage' and 'https://webpage.company.com' should in most cases be the same. You can see it this way: it doesn't matter what the target URL is, traffic is still coming from the same host, the same IP address.

In any case, you most probably don't need to worry about any traffic leaving your local network.